# Bootstrap 3 popup with link?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a small issue with linking or so called referencing text with Bootstrap pop up windows I am not sure how it works here is the code:

When the user clicks on My little Pontus 2 it should popup with a popup window with text "...".

```html
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">My little Pontus 2</a>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to include all the required libraries to your project. Those are, `jquery`, `bootstrap css` and `bootstrap js` files.

And then you'll need to give an `id` to your `Modal` and include that `id` on your `link` along with the `data-toggle="modal"` so that the link triggers the required `modal`.

Here's your updated code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">My little Pontus 2</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EdgarAxe No, it doesn't close unless you click outside the `Modal` box.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this : (you missing the `data-toggle="modal"` )

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

more at : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: This did not work when ever I click on it it dosent pop up.

Comment: Tushar Khatiwada is right, you forgot to include jquery and boostrap.css :)